# Radar chart in react native

Tags: react-native, charts

I want to plot a radar chart of users using my app based on their latitude and longitude data and respective to the latitude and longitude of the current user with an option to limit the chart to only users surrounding the current user upto a maximum of 10 kms. How can such a chart be rendered in react native ? Also the chart must be interactive, meaning that the plotted dots of users should be clickable which on clicking must show the clicked users data as in like a tool tip or pop up. Please see the attached image which is an example of what i want to achieve. [image]